# One AD user Multiple Logins

Tags: windows, active-directory, login

I have a department of 20 users or so, which basically work in shifts but access the same desktop and settings, I am thinking to join these computers (15 computers) to AD and create only ONE account for e.g. ContactCentre, so that they can authenticate against AD and have the same settings.

Question is, can a AD account login simultaneously from different machines or would it be a problem ? Any other suggestion in this scenario would be very helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> can a AD account login simultaneously
>   from different machines or would it be
>   a problem ?

Yes, it certainly can, but it's a horrible practice from a security and maintenance point of view. You already have AD, so why don't you take advantage of it and create an account for each user. You can look into using mandatory profiles if you want to ensure they all get the same desktop configuration.

Comment: +1 For individual accounts and mandatory profiles.

Comment: Yes, go for individual accounts.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, an AD account can log in to multiple machines at once.  However, you should consider creating accounts for each individual.  If for nothing more than making sure one user doesn't end up locking out the account or changing the password.